# R2 SCORE. Scikit Learn vs StatsModels

Tags: regression, python, regression-coefficients, descriptive-statistics

I have the next code (and question):

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.metrics as skl
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [30, 28, 32, 25, 25, 25, 22, 24, 35, 40]
y_true = [25, 30.5, 28.61, 38.87, 25.11, 26.08, 22.13, 25.31, 35.32, 36.22]
model = sm.OLS(y_true, x) # simple regression (univariate)
y_pred = model.predict( model.fit().params )
```

I using the r2 score from sklearn:

```
skl.r2_score(y_true, y_pred)
```

I obtain:

```
0.13641808463593941
```

But, when I get the summary of model, using StatsModel api:

```
print(model.fit().summary())
```

I obtain:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
=========================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 y   R-squared:                       0.972
Model:                       OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.969
```

Which would make sense, since most predicted data are very approximate.

```
plt.plot( y_true, y_pred , 'yo', color = "orange" )
plt.show()
```

[image: y_true vs y_pred]

- Which of the R-squared(R2) is correct?
- What is the difference?
- Which should I use in a regression model?

Comment: Most interestingly, np.corrcoef(y_true, y_pred)[0, 1]**2 again returns another value: 0.32883658983348035

Comment: Ohh! I get confused even more ...  #_#

Comment: see this question for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036866/scikit-learn-is-returning-coefficient-of-determination-r2-values-less-than-1/

Comment: see previous questions and answers to statsmodels doesn't add a constant and rsquared changes definition depending on the presence of a constant. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24851787/statsmodels-calculate-fitted-values-and-r-squared/24852415#24852415

Comment: yep, i have seen the all responses, but, How do I "tell" the function (sklearn r2_score) that my model has an intercept if it only asks me for two numerical arrays (y_true & y_pred)?

Comment: I think "generalized r2" (goo.gl/LvABcO) might be of help, but how to program it?

Comment: Re. @jonanthrax comment on how to get the intercept in the model:
`LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False) #no intercept`; `LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True) #intercept`.